# VBA Macro to automate histogram throwing error 400

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro to produce a histogram, given a certain selection.  The code for the macro looks like this

```
Sub HistogramHelper(M As Range)
Dim src_sheet As Worksheet
Dim new_sheet As Worksheet
Dim selected_range As Range
Dim r As Integer
Dim score_cell As Range
Dim num_scores As Integer
Dim count_range As Range
Dim new_chart As Chart


    Set selected_range = M
    Set src_sheet = ActiveSheet
    Set new_sheet = Application.Sheets.Add(After:=src_sheet)
    title = selected_range.Cells(1, 1).Value
    new_sheet.Name = title

    ' Copy the scores to the new sheet.
    new_sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Data"
    r = 2
    For Each score_cell In selected_range.Cells
        If Not IsNumeric(score_cell.Text) Then
            'MsgBox score_cell.Text
        Else
            new_sheet.Cells(r, 1) = score_cell
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Next score_cell

    num_scores = selected_range.Count     

    'Creates the number of bins to 5
    'IDEA LATER: Make this number equal to Form data
    Dim num_bins As Integer
    num_bins = 5

    ' Make the bin separators.
    new_sheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Bins"
    For r = 1 To num_bins
        new_sheet.Cells(r + 1, 2) = Str(r)
    Next r

    ' Make the counts.
    new_sheet.Cells(1, 3) = "Counts"
    Set count_range = new_sheet.Range("C2:C" & num_bins + 1)

    'Creates frequency column for all counts
    count_range.FormulaArray = "=FREQUENCY(A2:A" & num_scores + 1 & ",B2:B" & num_bins & ")"

    'Make the range labels.
    new_sheet.Cells(1, 4) = "Ranges"
    For r = 1 To num_bins
        new_sheet.Cells(r + 1, 4) = Str(r)
        new_sheet.Cells(r + 1, 4).HorizontalAlignment = _
            xlRight
    Next r

    ' Make the chart.
    Set new_chart = Charts.Add()
    With new_chart
        .ChartType = xlBarClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=new_sheet.Range("C2:C" & _
            num_bins + 1), _
            PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, _
            Name:=new_sheet.Name
    End With

    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .HasLegend = False
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = title
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, _
            xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Scores"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text _
 _
            = "Out of " & num_scores & " responses"

        ' Display score ranges on the X axis.
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & _
            new_sheet.Name & "'!R2C4:R" & _
            num_bins + 1 & "C4"

    End With
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    With ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1)
        .Overlap = 0
        .GapWidth = 0
        .HasSeriesLines = False
        .VaryByCategories = False

    End With

    r = num_scores + 2
    new_sheet.Cells(r, 1) = "Average"
    new_sheet.Cells(r, 2) = "=AVERAGE(A1:A" & num_scores & _
        ")"
    r = r + 1
    new_sheet.Cells(r, 1) = "StdDev"
    new_sheet.Cells(r, 2) = "=STDEV(A1:A" & num_scores & ")"
End Sub
```

I am currently using a WorkBook that looks like this:
[image]

Eventually, I want to produce a macro that automatically iterates over each column, calling the Histogram Helper function with each column, producing multiple histograms over multiple worksheets.  For now, I'm just trying to test putting in TWO ranges into HistogramHelper, like so:

```
Sub GenerateHistograms()

    HistogramHelper Range("D3:D30")
    HistogramHelper Range("E3:E30")

End Sub
```

However, upon running the Macro, I get a dialog box with the error number `400`, one of the sheets is produced successfully with the worksheet title Speaker, and another sheet is produced with a numerical title and no content.

What is going on?

**Edit**: The workbook in question: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6Gtk320qmNFbGhMaU5ST3JFQUE/edit?usp=sharing

**Edit 2- Major WTF?**:

I switched the beginning FOR block to this for debugging purposes:

```
For Each score_cell In selected_range.Cells
        If Not IsNumeric(score_cell.Text) Then
            MsgBox score_cell.Address 'Find which addresses don't have numbers
        Else
            new_sheet.Cells(r, 1) = score_cell
        End If
        r = r + 1
Next score_cell
```

Whenever you run this, no matter which range you put as the second Macro call (in this case E3:E30) the program prints out that each cell $E$3- $E$30 is a non-text character.  Why oh why?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but from msdn:    error 400 = Form already displayed; can't show modally (version 97)  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146864

Comment: Maybe you're trying to set a sheet tab name to something which is not a valid value?  No error text? - just 400?

Comment: There's no error text, just 400.  I suspect the issue is that I'm either a) trying to set a sheet tab to a non-valid string or b) naming a sheet something that already exists.  However, I have no idea why that's happening-- the relevant code is title = selected_range.Cells(1, 1).Value, which should give the first value in the selected range, which in this case would be D3 and E3.  Those are different strings!! What's going on?

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify the sheet name in the range that you pass to HistogramHelper?

Comment: I passed in a title, and now the error doesn't pop up, but the new sheet contains no data-- data which should have been copied from E3:E30.  I've been at debugging this for hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you need this?

```
Sheets(title).Activate
```

TIP: for this kind of recursive implementations implying many creations/deletions and getting every day more and more complex, I wouldn't ever rely on "Active" elements (worksheet, range, etc.), but in specific ones (sheets("whatever")) avoiding problems and easing the debugging.

------------------------ UPDATE

No, apparently, you don't need it.
Then, update `selected_range.Cells(1, 1).Value` such that it takes different values for each new worksheet, because this is what is provoking the error: creating two worksheets with the same name.

------------------------ UPDATE 2 (after downloading the spreadsheet)

The problem was what I thought: two worksheets created with the same name (well... not exactly: one of the spreadhsheets was intended to be called after a null variable). And the reason for this problem, what I thought too: relying on "Active elements". But the problem was not while using the ActiveSheet, but while passing the arguments: the ranges are given without spreadsheet and were taken from the last created spreadsheet. Thus, solution:

```
HistogramHelper Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3:D30")
HistogramHelper Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E30")
```

Bottom line: don't rely on "Active"/not-properly-defined elements for complex situations.

Comment: Where would I put this?  Putting it upon naming the sheet does not work.

Comment: Right after creating the new worksheet; you are relying on the active sheet but are not updating this variable. The active sheet is every time the same, the first one.

Comment: Proper explanation: I did include this in my code right after creating the new worksheet and it works (because updates the active worksheet which is properly used in the next iteration). Better is calling the sheets by their names, instead "pss, sheet, look here" ;)

Comment: This doesn't work-- the ActiveSheet is not supposed to change.  Sheet1 is the source of all the relevant data, and it needs to stay like that

Comment: Yes? Ok. If this is the case, then you should change the cell from which it reads the name because it reads two times the same cell and thus the same name, what is what provokes the error. I performed the modification described above and the code works fine (perhaps the data is taken from the wrong place but the worksheets are named properly and there is no crash).

Comment: Can you download the spreadsheet in the Google Drive and see why it is not working with your code modification?  I can't see why the same cell is getting called twice.  You mind explaining?

Comment: No problem. I have requested permission to download.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The same cell is not being called (pretty tough day, pretty late, etc.), but I don't know if the same value is used or not.  Give me permission to download the spreadsheet and will come back to you in one minute.

Comment: Awesome!  Try to download again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31890/discussion-between-varocarbas-and-parseltongue)